# Redirect standard output with Applescript

Tags: applescript

How can I redirect the output of an application I start with "tell" to stdout/stderr?

I want to do (doesn't work)

```
tell application "application > log.txt"
    // ...
    quit
end tell
```

or

```
tell application "application" redirect output to "log.txt"
    // ...
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: No, you can't. What output do you expect?

Comment: What vadian said. I mean, you can easily save any text to a log.txt file, but telling iTunes to play and quit doesn't produce any output.

Comment: I used iTunes as an example. I really meant "any application".